# how to fix resources of unpacked .exe file

Tags: reverse-engineering, cracking

I want to translate a program but this program is packed.I unpacked program but can't change menu or dialog or other resources of program by resource editing tools,because resources divide to other section.please help me how can I fix or collect  divided resources of program from other section on memory to .res section of program?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought about the legal consequences of making about cracking a program?

Comment: yes..I know what I'm doing

Answer (score -1):

Locate the strings and translate them directly in Hex, rather than use any Resource Editor.